# Postgres using named column in where clause

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres I'm struggling with this syntax. It works in mysql but not sure what I'm doing wrong is.

So let's say I have a json document. I want to select a column in that document and return the result as "text"

So my query would look like this.

```
SELECT member_id, data->>'username' AS username
FROM player.player
```

Returns this as expected.

[image: result]

Now lets say I want to select a name from the column so my query would look like this.

```
SELECT member_id, data->>'username' AS username
FROM player.player WHERE username LIKE 'sam'
```

When I run the query I get this.

[image: result 2]'

Why does it do that? The json I'm returning is returning as text data type since I'm using `json->>` on a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL is based on SQL standard, and there are not possible to use a alias on same query level. You should to use derived table and filter on higher level:

```
postgres=# select 1 as x where x = 1;
ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
LINE 1: select 1 as x where x = 1;
                        ^
postgres=# select * from (select 1 as x) s where x = 1;
┌───┐
│ x │
╞═══╡
│ 1 │
└───┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: what is the "s" before the where clause? wouldn't it be easier to do this? `SELECT member_id, data->>'username' AS username
FROM player.player WHERE data->>'username' = 'sam'`

Comment: `s` is subselect alias. Your variant is +/- effectively same like mine. Depends what you prefer